# How to customise Org-mode per file (and sync with Orgzly)

Tags: org-mode, files, customize

I am using Org-mode in conjunction with an Android tablet. I have customized Org-mode and keep files in Dropbox. After sync the Android side is not implementing any customization.

Copied this code to the head of the file:

```el
(setq org-log-into drawer "LOGBOOK")
(setq org-use-fast-todo-selection '(prefix))
(SETQ ORG-todo-keywords
          '((sequence "TODO(t!)" "|" "DONE(d!)" "REPEAT(r!)")))
(setq org-todo-keyword-faces
          '(("TODO" . org-warning)
            ("DONE" . "yellow")
            ("REPEAT" . (:foreground "blue" :weight bold)))
```

But it does not get implemented in the Android side.

What am I missing?

Comment: Orgzly is not a full implementation of either Emacs or org-mode. Have you looked into the customization options in the app?

Answer (score 2):

[Orgzly](http://www.orgzly.com/) doesn't execute elisp code in your org files, so it won't pick up the settings.  It also doesn't see per-file settings of todo keywords (the  `#+SEQ_TODO` and `#+TYP_TODO` keywords).  You can specify your todo keywords and which represent DONE states in Orgzly's settings.